# Problem With Â character

Tags: php, mysql

My php Sql is inserting Â with £ like "Â£" in a Database field ITEM_NAME. Actully this is an Iphone Application and I am using this ITEM_NAME for comparing values. I dont want to add Â with £. I have utf8_general_ci in database for this field.

I gone through almost all the post related to that. Can any body please help me about this ?

I apologize for less explaination. I want to know can i insert £ into database without having Â. Actully once it enters in the database as Â£ and then it causes comparison problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enforce utf-8 in several places:

- The column should accept utf-8 (done)
- The connection should be utf-8
- The form sending the value and the page showing results should have utf-8 encoding meta header and be saved as utf-8

Comment: +1 A lot of people forget that utf-8 has to be enforced across the board.

Comment: I apologize for less explaination. I want to know can i insert £ into database without having Â. Actully once it enters in the database as Â£ and then it causes comparison problems.

Comment: In short, yes! See [Tips for Supporting UTF-8 in Your PHP5 Applications](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/07/tips-for-supporting-utf-8-in-your-php5-applications/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The database is utf8_general_ci as the field?

Have you tried  the function 
[utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-decode.php)

I've a similar problem with CakePhp and I've to set the encoding in the Database file configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysqli_set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) before every query (or mysql_set_charset()) and ensure that your data itself is in unicode, too.

Answer (score 0):

Run `SET NAMES "utf8"` before your query or set it in my.cnf as `default-character-set=utf8`.